# How can I call a parent function from ui-modal AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-modal

Here is my modal function:

```
$uibModal.open({
   templateUrl: config.baseUrl + '/ClientApp/Views/Modals/userEditModal.html' + config.scriptVersion,
   size: size,
   scope: $scope,
   controller: function ($scope, $uibModalInstance) {                
     $scope.cancel = function () {
       $uibModalInstance.close();
     };
   }
}).result.catch(function (resp) {           
   if (['cancel', 'backdrop click', 'escape key press'].indexOf(resp) === -1) {
     throw resp;
   }
})
```

This `$uibModal` is inside a controller where I have other `$scope` variables and functions. If I do an `ng-repeat` inside the modal with a parent scope object the `ng-repeat` works! But if I call a function ex. `doSomething()` or try to use a scope object in `ng-class` ex. `ng-class="{'css': doSomething()}"` - it doesn't. As you can see I assigned `$scope` to the scope property in the modal. What am I doing wrong? I also tried calling the function with `$parent` and still doesn't work ex. `ng-if="$parent.doSomething()"`

Answer (score 0):

What about just using a reference to the function that already exists when you define the modal ? [bind a property to your controller's scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-bindtocontroller-) and pass it around to your modal.

```
bindToController: true,
controllerAs: 'parent'
```

Then just pass `doSomething`

```
function myController($uibModal) {

    var parent = this;
    parent.doSomething = function() {
        /** does something ... **/
    };

    $uibModal.open({
       templateUrl: config.baseUrl + '/ClientApp/Views/Modals/userEditModal.html' + config.scriptVersion,
       size: size,
       scope: $scope,
       controller: function ($scope, $uibModalInstance) {  

         $scope.doSomethingDelegate = parent.doSomething;

         // ... more stuff
       }
    })
}
```

And then in your modal template

```
<element ng-if="doSomethingDelegate()"></element>
```